# how to add a (given) private key in ssh whose public key is already setup on server

Tags: ssh

I KNOW how to setup a new ssh key pair with github.

If someone gave me a private key and told me to connect to a server via ssh on a mac, how do I set this up?

NOTE: I can't change the server settings.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the standard [OpenSSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openssh) is available on your Mac; if you're using a pretty GUI program, then this might not work. I also assume you've been given an OpenSSH-standard key. (The commercial [ssh.com](http://www.ssh.com/) keys might be formatted differently; at least they were a decade ago, when I last used a provider that still used the commercial SSH.)

Perhaps you already have a private key; check `ls -l ~/.ssh/id_*` to see if you already have a private key installed. If you do (and you want to keep that key) then you'll have more work to do.

If you don't already have a private key, take a look at the first line of the file. It'll look something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If it says `RSA`, like mine, then store the file into `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. If it says `DSA`, store it into `~/.ssh/id_dsa`.

If the `~/.ssh` directory does not exist yet, create it:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

The `chmod 700` is important -- `ssh` is picky about permissions: if even group write is available, you may have problems.

I don't know the easiest way to store the file. If you have a standalone file (email attachment, web site download, etc.), you can simply move the file into place:

```
mv Path/to/the/file ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The `chmod 600` is important -- `ssh` is picky about permissions: if even group read is available, you may have problems. I'm not kidding -- I've spent too much of my life debugging connection problems that came down to over-strict permissions checking by `ssh`. You could make it `400` and prevent yourself from mistakenly overwriting it, but mine is `600` with no ill consequences.

If you've got the file copy-and-pasted into an email text or web page text, you'll need to use a text editor of some sort to save the file, via copy-and-paste of the text itself. (Don't use Word. BBEdit or TextMate or .. whatever Apple calls their plain text editor .. would work.)

Now test it:

```
ssh hostname
```

e.g.:

```
$ ssh haig
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sarnold/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

If you need to give a username too:

```
ssh username@hostname
```

The important piece is the *for key* -- if it just asks for a password, it is probably a password for the remote endpoint, and that won't work. If it asks for the passphrase for the key, then you're running.

---

If you already have a private key you wish to keep using, store the file into something else; e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_mithra`, and then add a new `Host` entry into a `~/.ssh/config` configuration file:

```
host mithra
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_for_mithra
```

Here, I've assumed the hostname is `mithra`. Use whatever name or IP address you've been given.

---

The `~/.ssh/config` file can also be used to specify a per-host username if you want to avoid giving it on the command line all the time.

And the final note: most `ssh` users use the `ssh-agent` to store a decrypted version of their private key rather than re-type the passphrase to unlock it all the time. I understand [an ssh agent is integrated into OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent#Status_on_Mac_OS_X) these days -- it would be worth investigating how to use it. Perhaps it is as simple as running `ssh-add` first. (I like `ssh-add -t 3600`, so the key works for an hour before the decrypted version is thrown away. That helps protect the key material somewhat if I walk away from my workstation without requiring my to run `ssh-add -D` when I leave.)

Comment: One handy way to always create the `.ssh` directory with the "right" permissions is to just run `ssh localhost` as that user (it'll fail to log in, but in the process of failing, it'll create the `.ssh` directory).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. Unfortunately, it didn't help. I've setup ssh in the past (for github) and it's usually two lines of instructions and I've had no issues. A quick search on this "ssh private key" will generate a million results on google.

Comment: @amber: Oh! That makes sense, I should have known the `ssh` team would have been kind enough to create the missing directory. Thanks.

Comment: @pritam: where are you stuck? I perhaps gave a too-comprehensive answer since there were many unknown variables. Do you already have a private key in your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `~/.ssh/id_dsa`? Will you use the same username on both hosts or do you need to use a different username on the other host? Did you successfully store the private key into a file? With what permissions? Do you get any error messages when you try to `ssh` to the remote host? Do you get any error messages when you try to add the key to your `ssh-agent`?

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while looking for a way to manage Amazon EC2 keys. Like you, I already had a key for github.

---

What I did was duplicate the existing `id_rsa` file.

```
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_amazonhost.pem
```

And then replace the contents of this new file (`id_rsa_amazonhost.pem`) via cut/paste with the private key provided by Amazon.

Then I added an entry to ~/.ssh/config (replace `my-hostname` and `my-username` as appropriate).

```
Host my-hostname.example.com
    IdentityFile  ~/.ssh/id_rsa_amazonhost.pem
    User my-username
```

This allowed me to `ssh my-hostname` as desired.

---

For a one-time connection, you can skip the ~/.ssh/config file and simply run

> ssh -i id_rsa_amazonhost.pem my-username@my-hostname